# Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [RCTModalHostViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Tags: ios, react-native, popover, landscape

I have app in react native on iOS which I locked it on landscape mode by doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {
Orientation.lockToLandscape()
}
```

I added a popover window but when I press on it im getting this error:

```
 Exception thrown while executing UI block:
 Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application,
 and [RCTModalHostViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
```

on app.delegate I added this function:

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]) {
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
 }

 return [Orientation getOrientation];
   }
```

on portrait this error doesn't happened

How can I fix it... thank you

Answer (score 10):

I found root cause of this issue. This is happening with modal window. My video is opening in the Modal Window and when I am changing from Portrait to landscape it getting this error.

Solution:

```
<Modal
  visible={true}
  supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'landscape']}
>
```